# How can I implement loops that don't use potentially very large amounts of heapspace in ZIO

Tags: scala, zio

I know that ZIO is maintains its own stack, namely `zio.internal.FiberContext#stack`, which protects recursive functions like

```scala
def getNameFromUser(askForName: UIO[String]): UIO[String] =
  for {
    resp <- askForName
    name <- if (resp.isEmpty) getNameFromUser(askForName) else ZIO.succeed(resp)
  } yield name
```

from stack overflows. However, they still consume space in the ZIO interpreter stack, which can result in `OutOfMemoryError` for very deep recursions. How would you rewrite the `getNameFromUser` function from above, to not blow the heap even when the `askForName` effect returns empty strings for a very long time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to rewrite the function from above is to use an appropriate [Schedule](https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/datatypes_schedule), as suggested by [toxicafunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7190513/toxicafunk), resulting in

```scala
def getNameFromUserSchedule(askForName: UIO[String]): UIO[String] =
  askForName.repeat(Schedule.doWhile(_.isEmpty))
```

This is both concise and readable, and consumes only a constant amount of ZIO stack frames.

However, you don't have to use [Schedule](https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/datatypes_schedule) to make

```scala
def getNameFromUser(askForName: UIO[String]): UIO[String] =
  for {
    resp <- askForName
    name <- if (resp.isEmpty) getNameFromUser(askForName) else ZIO.succeed(resp)
  } yield name
```

consume a constant amount of ZIO stack frames. It could also be done like so:

```scala
def getNameFromUser(askForName: UIO[String]): UIO[String] =
  askForName.flatMap { resp =>
    if (resp.isEmpty) getNameFromUser(askForName) else ZIO.succeed(resp)
  }
```

This function looks almost like the original in its desugared form, which is

```scala
def getNameFromUser(askForName: UIO[String]): UIO[String] =
  askForName.flatMap { resp =>
    if (resp.isEmpty) getNameFromUser(askForName) else ZIO.succeed(resp)
  }.map(identity)
```

The only difference is the final `map(identity)`. When interpreting a ZIO value generated from this function, the interpreter has to push the `identity` on the stack, compute the `flatMap`, and then apply the `identity`. However, to compute the `flatMap`, the same procedure might repeat, forcing the interpreter to push as many `identities` on the stack as we have loop iterations. This is kind of annoying, but the interpreter cannot know, that the functions it pushes on the stack are in fact identities. You can eliminate them without dropping the nice `for` syntax, by using the [better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) compiler plugin, that is able to optimize away the final `map(identity)` when desugaring for comprehensions.

Without the `map(identity)`, the interpreter will execute `askForName`, and then use the closure

```scala
resp =>
    if (resp.isEmpty) getNameFromUser(askForName) else ZIO.succeed(resp)
```

to obtain the next ZIO value for interpretation. This procedure might repeat an arbitrary number of times, but the size of the interpreter stack will remain unchanged.

Summarizing, here is a brief discussion about when the ZIO interpreter will use its internal stack:

1. When computing chained `flatMaps`, like `io0.flatMap(f1).flatMap(f2).flatMap(f3)`. To evaluate an expression like this, the interpreter will push `f3` on the stack, and look at `io0.flatMap(f1).flatMap(f2)`. Then it will put `f2` on the stack and look at `io0.flatMap(f1)`. Finally `f1` will be put on the stack, and `io0` is evaluated (there is an optimization in the interpreter that might take a shortcut here, but that's not relevant for the discussion). After the evaluation of `io0` to `r0`, `f1` is popped from the stack, and applied to the result of `r0`, giving us a new ZIO value, `io1 = f1(r0)`. Now `io1` is evaluated to `r1` and `f2` is popped from the stack, to obtain the next ZIO value `io2 = f2(r1)`. Finally, `io2` is evaluated to `r2`, `f3` popped from the stack to obtain `io3 = f3(r2)` and `io3` is interpreted to `r3`, the final result of the expression. Thus, if you have an algorithm, that works by chaining together `flatMaps`, you should expect the maximum depth of the ZIO stack to be at least the length of your chain of `flatMaps`.
2. When computing chained folds, like `io.foldM(h1, f1).foldM(h2, f2).foldM(h3, f3)`, or mixtures of chained folds and chained `flatMaps`. If there are no errors, folds behave like `flatMaps`, so the analysis regarding the ZIO stack is quite similar. You should expect the maximum depth of the ZIO stack to be at least the length of your chain.
3. When applying the above rule, keep in mind, that there are many combinators, that are directly or indirectly implemented on top of `flatMap` and `foldCauseM`:

   - `map`, `as`, `zip`, `zipWith`,`<*`, `*>`, `foldLeft`, `foreach` are implemented on top of `flatMap`
   - `fold`, `foldM`, `catchSome`, `catchAll`, `mapError` are implemented on top of `foldCauseM`

Last but not least: You should not worry too much about the size of ZIOs internal stack, unless

- you are implementing an algorithm where the number of iterations might become arbitrary large for only moderately or even constantly sized input data
- you are traversing very large data structures, that don't fit into memory
- a user can influence the stack depth directly with very little effort (that means without sending you large amounts of data through the network for example)

Answer (score 5):

You're using a loop within a recursive function. Basically, every time you call `getNameFromUser` you are allocating objects to the heap, the heap can never free those objects because you objects created on t1, need the objects created in t2 to resolve, but the objects from t2 need that the objects on t3 to resolve ad infinitum.

Instead of a loop you should use a ZIO combinator just as `forever` or any other you can find on [Schedule](https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/datatypes_schedule)

```
 import zio.Schedule

 val getNameFromUser: RIO[Console, String] = for {
  _    <- putStrLn("Waht is your name")
  name <- zio.console.getStrLn
 } yield name

 val runUntilNotEmpty = Schedule.doWhile[String](_.isEmpty)

 rt.unsafeRun(getNameFromUser.repeat(runUntilNotEmpty))
```

[EDIT] Adding a different example cuz all you actually need is:

```
import zio._
import zio.console._
import scala.io.StdIn

object ConsoleEx extends App {

  val getNameFromUser = for {
    _    <- putStrLn("What is your name?")
    name <- getStrLn
    _    <- putStr(s"Hello, $name")
  } yield ()

  override def run(args: List[String]) =
    getNameFromUser.fold(t => {println(t); 1}, _ => 0)

}
```

Note, however, that i you jhave `fork in run := true` in your `build.sbt` then you will also need to add `run / connectInput := true` as explained [in the sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html#Configuring+Input)